# Scan multiple variables depending on test cases?

Tags: c

I want to calculate sum of arithmetic progression in which we have to take 3 variables from user. a=first number, b= step size/increment, c=length of sequence.
If there are more than 1 test case ,  say three, then I have to scan a,b,c three time. How to do this?
E.g scanf (" %d %d %d", a,b,c); 3 times without affect initial values in first test case.

Comment: If you know the exact number of times, use a for loop. Otherwise use a while loop (and choose a sensible exit condition). When you say without affecting the initial values, are you wanting to store these in an array for later use?

Comment: If I have 2 test cases a,b,c = 1 , 2 , 5 then sum of progession wud be 1+ 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 25 ,

Comment: In 2nd case I can have a,b,c = 4, 2 , 10 and so on. Basically I want to use values of a,b,c every time to calculate new sum .

Comment: So, you can just print out the results (or return them) and then do it again?

Answer (score 1):

If you know no of test cases read it first and store it in a variable.

```
int calculate_ap(int a, int b, int c)
{
    //Implement function to calculate Arithmetic progression and return the result
}

int main()
{
    int test_cases = 0;
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d", &test_cases); //Reads no of test cases
    while(test_cases--)
   {
        scanf("%d, %d, %d", &a, &b, &c); //read A, B, C
        printf("%d\n", calculate_ap(a, b, c));
   }

}
```

Hope this helps.